# How to access JS object inside an array?

Tags: javascript

How am I going to access the firstnames or the lastnames?

```
[
  {name:"Name",value:{firstName:"John",lastName:"Doe"},
  {name:"Name",value:{firstName:"Juan",lastName:"delaCruz"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a typo in your code (the closing braces).

```
z = [
  {name:"Name",value:{firstName:"John",lastName:"Doe"}},
  {name:"Name",value:{firstName:"Juan",lastName:"delaCruz"}}
];

firstPersonsName = z[0].value.firstName

allFirstnames = z.map(function(n) { console.log(n.value.firstName); });
allLastnames = z.map(function(n) { console.log(n.value.lastName); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is named `arr`, you can access first names with `arr[i].value.firstName` and last names with `arr[i].value.lastName` where `i` is the array index of the item you want to access.